# Filter duplicates combining multiple columns

Tags: mysql

### Example table

```
| name         | year | latitude | longitude |
|--------------|------|----------|-----------|
| Cleveland    | 1800 | 10       | 11        |
| Cleveland    | 1810 | 10       | 11        |
| Medina       | 1811 | 12       | 13        |
| Dayton       | 1812 | 14       | 15        |
| Sandusky     | 1105 | 50       | 50        |
| Mount Vernon | 1813 | 50       | 50        |
```

### What I'm aiming to do

I want to select each unique combinations of `latitude` and `longitude`. So I want to filter out any duplicate pairs. I also need to filter out any records whose year is less than `1500`.

This is the subset I'm trying to achieve:

```
| name         | year | latitude | longitude |
|--------------|------|----------|-----------|
| Cleveland    | 1800 | 10       | 11        |
| Medina       | 1811 | 12       | 13        |
| Dayton       | 1812 | 14       | 15        |
| Mount Vernon | 1813 | 50       | 50        |
```

Each records `year` is greater than 1500 and there aren't any duplicate lat,long pairs.

### What I've tried

I've tried to find a way to use `DISTINCT`. Nothing I've found has worked.

I also have tried using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
GROUP BY latitude, longitude
HAVING year > 1500;
```

The issue with the above query is that is eliminates both of the following records which contain the lat,long pair of 50,50:

```
| name         | year | latitude | longitude |
|--------------|------|----------|-----------|
| Sandusky     | 1105 | 50       | 50        |
| Mount Vernon | 1813 | 50       | 50        |
```

The group is eliminated because Sandusky's `year` is less than 1500. I don't want Sandusky's record, but I do want Mount Vernon.

I noticed that if if the two records where switched like so:

```
| name         | year | latitude | longitude |
|--------------|------|----------|-----------|
| Mount Vernon | 1813 | 50       | 50        |
| Sandusky     | 1105 | 50       | 50        |
```

...then the group's year is set as 1813 and the group is not eliminated. I thought maybe sorting by year would fix it, but it didn't:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
GROUP BY latitude, longitude
HAVING year > 1500
ORDER BY year DESC;
```

Is what I'm attempting possible?

Comment: Have you done anything with `DISTINCT`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, MAX(users.year) as `year`, latitude, longitude
FROM users
WHERE year > 1500
GROUP BY latitude, longitude;
```

Results in:

```
| 7 | Columbus     | 1978 | 7  | 8  
| 1 | Cleveland    | 1800 | 10 | 11 
| 3 | Medina       | 1811 | 12 | 13 
| 4 | Dayton       | 1812 | 14 | 15 
| 6 | Mount Vernon | 1813 | 50 | 50
```

The only difference is where the `WHERE`/`HAVING` is, because it is before the `GROUP BY` statement, it will do the filtering BEFORE the grouping happens and thus you get the desired result.

The `MAX(users.year)`ensure that you always get the largest year on the set.  If this doesn't matter to you, you can replace `` SELECT `id`, `name`, MAX(users.year) as `year`, latitude, longitude `` with `SELECT *`

Comment: The `MAX()` isn't necessary, just using `WITH`above the `GROUP BY` did the trick. Thank you, as usual you're one step ahead!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I didn't understand the problem, but it would be this simple:

```
select * from users u where u.year > 1500;
```

I don't know what you want to do in case there are more than one pair of the same coordinates with a year greater than 1500.

Answer (score 1):

How about this unless it is a misread. I did read. It makes assumptions like you want to not eliminate a different name with same lat,long

```
create table users
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(50) not null,
    year int not null,
    latitude int not null,
    longitude int not null
);
truncate table users;
insert users (name,year,latitude,longitude) values
('Cleveland',1810,10,11),
('Medina',1811,12,13),
('Dayton',1812,14,15),
('Mount Vernon',1813,50,50),
('Sandusky',1105,50,50);

SELECT distinct name,year,latitude,longitude 
FROM users 
where year > 1500 
ORDER BY year;
+--------------+------+----------+-----------+
| name         | year | latitude | longitude |
+--------------+------+----------+-----------+
| Cleveland    | 1810 |       10 |        11 |
| Medina       | 1811 |       12 |        13 |
| Dayton       | 1812 |       14 |        15 |
| Mount Vernon | 1813 |       50 |        50 |
+--------------+------+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: I'm testing this against my actual data. I think I misunderstood how `DISTINCT` works. I thought that if, say there was another record: `('Columbus', 1813, 7, 8)`  ... it would be eliminated since the year is not distinct. Apparently `DISTINCT` is looking at the *combination* of all the columns you specify.

Comment: it does. exactly. not quite sure what ya want distinct-wise. let us know

Comment: can do just about anything you want by adding subqueries, like distinct lat,long, but bring back the oldest cityname, anything

Comment: Ok, the problem is that in the case of these: `('Columbus', 1813, 7, 8), ('Columbus', 1978, 7, 8)` it keeps both because the years are different. So I end up with duplicate lat,long pairs.

Comment: fair enough. which one do you want to keep ?

Comment: so the min you want, always, keeping distinct name

Comment: how would Chicago, 1800, 10, 11 fair in all this ? See, the question is not well formed. Ambiguous to say the least

Comment: In the case of those two Columbus records, I don't care. They both have a year greater than 1500, but I only want one because I want only one records with 7,8 ... Chicago would be skipped since Cleveland has 10,11 for its coords ... And I don't care if the name is distinct, but I do need to `SELECT` it.

Comment: how would the computer skip it ? not how would you write the sql, how can you describe in ENGLISH how Cleveland is picked up and Chicago isn't. That is why I chose those #s. So I take English, and I write the sql, and you and the computer are both happy

Comment: Chicago is skipped because keeping it would mean the result set has two instances of the coords 10,11.

Comment: of course it would be a dupe of 10,11. We need to tell the computer what is so special about Cleveland. And you haven't done that yet

Comment: I could just as easily say Cleveland would be skipped for the same reason. But I wouldn't clue the db engine into how that actually happens, now have i

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88166/discussion-between-jared-flack-and-drew).